# Stimulus check for resident alien on 2020 tax return

Tags: united-states, income-tax, f1-student-visa, stimulus

As a F1 student, I was nonresident alien from 2015-2019, then my status changed to resident alien at 2020. But, as you know, this status change happens at August 2020, I didn’t get the stimulus check, which is eligible to resident alien. What should I do to get stimulus check in this tax return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would file a 2020 tax return (on form 1040 since you were a resident alien), and you would claim the Recovery Rebate Credit on line 30. See the instructions for line 30 for the worksheet to calculate the credit that you should get. It should be $1,800 assuming your income is low and you are filing by yourself.

Note that in order to be eligible for this credit, you must have a Social Security Number that is "valid for employment" (i.e. your card does not say "Not Valid for Employment") issued before the due date of 2020 tax returns (April 15, 2021, or October 15, 2021 if you get an extension). You do not qualify for the stimulus money if you don't have a Social Security Number.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! In my SSN, it says that “Valid for work only with DHS Authorization.” I think this is pretty similar to the expression “Valid for employment,” so I hope I can get it :)

Comment: @user124697: Yes, that is an SSN valid for employment.